# Use BufferedImage in JLabel HTML?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage

Is it possible I can used a BufferedImage in a JLabel's HTML? Or do I have to save it locally and call it by a file path?

Comment: What do you mean by "a JLabel's HTML"?

Comment: You can use HTML in a JLabel to format it. Same with a tooltip and many JComponents that hold text.

Comment: Why?  `JLabel` has an `Icon` property?  Why not simply use `setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage))`?

Comment: @ThomasNield But the OP wants to use `BufferedImage`, presumably as a source to an `img` tag...I guess

Comment: Well, in the event I want to use more than one image. And also I am asking because I want to do the same thing in tooltips.

Comment: Then, yes, you will have to save the `BufferedImage` locally to disk and use `File#getURI#getURL` for the `src` attribute...

Comment: @MadProgrammer that is correct. I want to refer to it in the img tag somehow... or by any means that will get the job done

Comment: @MadProgrammer well that's just silly.. *sigh* might be better on performance to not have all the images loaded in memory anyway... but then it might take longer to load an image once the tooltip is called

Comment: The problem is, there simply isn't any sort of URL that says `memory://@someaddresswhichwouldverydangrous`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will need to save the image...

```
File tmp = File.create("buffer", ".png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", tmp);
```

Then you need to use the file's URL as the `src` attribute to the `img` tag...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
sb.append("<html><img src='");
sb.append(tmp.toURI().toURL());
sb.append("'></html>");
```

Then set that as the text to what ever...

```
label.setText(sb.toString());
label.setToolTipText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. And this file is actually temporary, meaning it is stored in memory but never saved, and will clean itself up?

Comment: No, it's temporaryly saved to disk, depending on the platform, it will be placed in the "tmp" directory.  If you want the file removed after the JVM exists, you should add `tmp.deleteOnExit()` after you've created it.